# Why aren't other table data are passing in a database in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am new in Codeigniter and i am experiencing a problem is sending a table data to the database. I have one row in a table by default and by clicking on the add activity button new rows are added by append of javascript. When i press submit button then only the first row data are passing to the database.

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
                 <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Activity Name" name="activity_name0" required ></td>
                 <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unit" name="activity_unit0" required></td>
                 <td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Weightage" name="activity_weightage0" required></td>
                 <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="100" name="activity_1000" required></td>
                 <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="75" name="activity_750" required ></td>
                 <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="50" name="activity_500" required ></td>
                 <td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="25" name="activity_250" required></td>
</tr>
```

Model:

```
class Addworkplan_model extends CI_Model{

public function addworkplan($id){

        $workplan_notification= 1;
        $workplan_status=1;

        $quater=$this->input->post('activity_quarter');
        if ($quater="one"){
            $workplan_month=$this->input->post('autumn');
        }
        elseif ($quater="two"){
            $workplan_month=$this->input->post('spring');
        }
        elseif($quater="three"){
            $workplan_month=$this->input->post('fall');
        }

            $data=array('workplan_quarter'=>$this->input->post('activity_quarter'),
                'workplan_month'=>$workplan_month,
                'workplan_date'=>$this->input->post('activity_date'),
                'workplan_activity'=>$this->input->post('activity_name'),
                'workplan_unit'=>$this->input->post('activity_unit'),
                'workplan_weightage'=>$this->input->post('activity_weightage'),
                'workplan_pi100'=>$this->input->post('activity_100'),
                'workplan_pi75'=>$this->input->post('activity_75'),
                'workplan_pi50'=>$this->input->post('activity_50'),
                'workplan_pi25'=>$this->input->post('activity_25'),
                'division_id'=>$id,
                'workplan_notification'=>$workplan_notification,
                'workplan_status'=>$workplan_status

                );

        print_r ($data);
        exit;
```

Javascript for append:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                count=1;
                $("button#addrowclick").click(function(){

                    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) { 


                    var add = '<tr><td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Activity Name" name="workplan activity_name" required></td>' + 
                    '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Unit" name="workplan activity_unit" required ></td>' + 
                    '<td class="col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Weightage" name="workplan activity_weightage" required ></td>' + 
                    '<td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="100" name="workplan activity_100" required ></td>' + 
                    '<td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="75" name="workplan activity_75" required ></td>' + 
                    '<td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="50" name="workplan activity_50" required ></td>' +
                    '<td class="col-md-1"><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="25" name="workplan activity_25" required ></td></tr>';
                    }
                    count=count+1;
                    //alert(count);
                    $('tbody').append(add);
                });
            });
```

I know that the name should be something different but i could not do that so any help will be appreciated. 
Thank You

Comment: For one thing: no spaces allowed in the `name` of an input. Second, if you expect multiple rows to be added, make sure the text inputs return arrays: `name="workplan_activity_name[]"`.

Comment: Its not working @Mudshark changing all that you had said. Only the first row of HTML data are going in the database but javascript aapped row are not going

Comment: Do you see the added text inputs when you put `print_r($this->input->post());` in the controller and hit submit on the form? You may be better off having the other text inputs already present in the html, but hidden initially (jQuery: `$('.optional').hide();` )

Comment: Do you suggesting to hide the html <tr> ?? It only shows the first row data  which is in html by using print_r($this->input->post());